# delete row corresponding to button clicked in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

```
  userdetails.jsp

  <tr>

 <td>
 <%
  out.println(rs.getString(1));
  name=rs.getString(1);
  out.print("<input type='hidden' name='user' value='"+name+"'");
  %>

</td>


<td>
<%out.println(rs.getString(2));

    %>
</td>
    <td>
          <%out.println(rs.getString(3));

    %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%out.println(rs.getString(4));

    %>
    </td>

    <td>
        <input type="Submit" name="delete_user" value="Delete"/>
    </td>

    </tr>
```

when i click the delete button only first row is getting deleted and not the row corresponding to which button is clicked

Answer (score 3):

You're putting multiple hidden input values and delete buttons altogether in the *same* form. When you use `request.getParameter()` to get the hidden input value, you will indeed only get the first one, regardless of the delete button pressed.

You need to *group* the hidden input and the delete button in their own forms.

```
<td>
    <form action="delete" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="delete_user" value="Delete" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>" />
    </form>
</td>
```

This way the request will always have the one and the right user name as parameter.

---

Said that, using *scriptlets* in JSP is 90's way of writing JSPs and also mingling database logic in a JSP is not really a good practice. I'd suggest to get yourself through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the user name to the button value upon clicking it:

```html
<input type="Submit" name="delete_user" value="Delete" onclick="this.value += ' <% out.print(name); %>'; this.disabled = true; " />
```

Then in the server side code, parse the value: get the text after first space, which is the user name to delete and reference only row with that user name.